# How to include index for the coefficients in series or sequence

Tags: list-manipulation, index

I am trying to use the "Summation" command for the exponent and for the corresponding subscript of the coefficient, but it fails. See the example below:

```
Sum[ai*x^i, {i, 1, 5}] = a x + 2 a x^2 + 3 a x^3 + 4 a x^4 + 5 a x^5
```

I want:

```
a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + a5 x^5
```

In a little complex form, I want the following expression to write "Summation":

```
(a0 + a1*x^1 + a2*x^2 + a3*x^3 + a4*x^4 + a5*x^5)/(b0 + b1*x^1 + 
 b2*x^2 + b3*x^3 + b4*x^4 + b5*x^5)
```

Likewise, how to make "Table" instead of "Summation" with or without the coefficients:
e.g.:

```
Table[x^i, {i, 1, 5}]/Table[x^j, {j, 0, 5}]
```

I want an output of the form:

```
{x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}/{x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}
```

Can someone have a look at this, please? Thanks.

Comment: Why not write something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTUYW.png)?

Comment: Yes, at least this part worked, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

Programmatically, it is much easier to deal with an indexed variable (e.g., `a[3]`, `b[5]`) than some arbitrary structured like `Subscript[a, 3]` or `a3`. However, you can display the indexed variable in any desired manner. For example,

```
(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {a, b, var};

tf[x_] := TraditionalForm@x

isum[var_, n_] = Inactive[Sum][var[k] x^k, {k, 0, n}]
```

[image]

```
StringForm["`` = ``", tf@isum[a, 5], tf@Activate@isum[a, 5]]
```

[image]

```
rp = isum[a, 5]/isum[b, 5];

StringForm["`` = ``", tf@rp, tf[rpa = Activate@rp]]
```

[image]

```
Inactive[Divide][List @@ Numerator[rpa], 
  List @@ Denominator[rpa]] /. {(a | b)[_] :> 1}
```

[image]

```
a[0] = 0;

Inactive[Divide][List @@ Numerator[rpa], 
  List @@ Denominator[rpa]] /. {(a | b)[_] :> 1}
```

[image]

Comment: In Mathematica 12.3, I get:  a (5) x^5 + a (4) x^4.......a(0)

Comment: Did you include `aa` in the list of indexed variables to be formatted  as `Subscripts`? That is, `(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {a, b, var, aa};`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Sum[Times[ToExpression[ToString[a] <> ToString[i]], x^i], {i, 1, 5}]
(*a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + a5 x^5*)
```

Or with Table:

```
Total[Table[
  Times[ToExpression[ToString[a] <> ToString[i]], x^i], {i, 1, 5}]]
(*a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + a5 x^5*)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to get the summation:

```
Total[Array[a, 5] x^Range[5]]

x a[1] + x^2 a[2] + x^3 a[3] + x^4 a[4] + x^5 a[5]
```

To get the ratio of two such things:

```
Total[Array[a, 5] x^Range[5]]/Total[Array[b, 6] x^Range[6]]

(x a[1] + x^2 a[2] + x^3 a[3] + x^4 a[4] + x^5 a[5])/
(x b[1] + x^2 b[2] + x^3 b[3] + x^4 b[4] + x^5 b[5] + x^6 b[6])
```

Comment: How is this of the form: a1 x + a2 x^2 + a3 x^3 + a4 x^4 + a5 x^5? Does ai=a[i]?

Comment: Yes.. use arrays like a[1] and a[2] instead of individually named variables like a1 and a2.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of E. Chan-López answer using `Indexed`

```
Total @ Table[x^i  Indexed[a, i], {i, 5}]
```

[image]